# How to get the reverse sorting to work with generic class types

Tags: java, sorting, generics

I have a class which has a generic attribute.

```
public class MyClass<T> {

    T data;

    MyClassType source;

    ZonedDateTime updatedTime;
}
```

I'm trying to sort a list of the above class containing different types of T this in reverse order

```
myClassList.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getUpdatedTime).reversed()); //Doesn't work
```

> Error:(372, 61) java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T,U
>       (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
>         method getUpdatedTime in class com.quicken.subscriptionservice.dtos.UnifiedHistoryResponse cannot be applied to given types
>           required: no arguments
>           found: java.lang.Object
>           reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>
> Error:(372, 62) java: invalid method reference
>     non-static method getUpdatedTime() cannot be referenced from a static context

If I remove ".reversed" in sort, it works without an issue.

Also if I modify my class to use Object class instead of Generic types as below, it works.

```
public class MyClass {

    Object data;

    MyClassType source;

    ZonedDateTime updatedTime;
}
```

Now the below sorting works

```
myClassList.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getUpdatedTime).reversed()); //Now works
```

I would be grateful if someone can help me understand how I can get reverse sort to work for the generic case and to help me understand why I'm getting the error mentioned above.

Comment: How is `myClassList` defined?  I suspect you are using a raw type.  Enable all compiler warnings to be notified of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to use generics using wildcard as below

```
myClassList.sort(Comparator.comparing((MyClass<?> r) -> r.getUpdatedTime()).reversed());
```

This is good enough for me. Hope it helps someone who's interested in the same question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Object class, you are casting objects to Object class. It is not generic programming. You need to parametrize the method reference.